# How do I remove the primary key on a table in Access?

Tags: vba, ms-access, dao

I have a frontend Access database with linked tables to a backend.  I'd like to be able to remove the primary key from a specific table with relative ease.  How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much searching, I discovered a very clean way to do this using DAO.  You don't even have to resort to ADO or using the Index collection to find the primary keys.

```
Public Function RemovePrimaryKey(ByRef tdf As TableDef)
    CurrentDb().Execute "DROP INDEX PRIMARYKEY ON [" & tdf.Connect & "].[" & tdf.Name & "];"
End Function
```